# Can't see image view when running app

Tags: android, android-layout

I have following XML

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/error_btn"
        android:layout_above="@+id/et_register_email"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/et_register_fullName"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/et_register_fullName"
        android:id="@+id/error_name"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

When I'm running my application this ImageView is not visible....

Comment: Why do you use `app:srcCompat` you want to laod vector graphics or? If you do, did you setup your `gradle` to support vector graphics?

Comment: Substitute app:srcCompact with android:background

Comment: thanks guys it works with android:background, app:srcCompat was generated automatically...

Comment: Use `android:src` instead

Comment: You are using a vector drawable and using a prelolipop device,, that's the true reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute `app:srcCompat="@drawable/error_btn"` with `android:background="@drawable/error_btn"`

Comment: if you want 'background` then you don't need an ImageView.

Comment: The actual problem is that the `src` used is vector and he didn't used the compatibility lib to dispay it in his device

Comment: @Pzy64 oh, I always used android:background. What is  app:srcCompat used for?